# Lebesgue integral is not injective?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I know that Lebesgue integral is not injective i.e. if

$$
\int\limits_{\Omega} f\, d\mu=\int\limits_{\Omega} g \,d\mu
$$

then it is not necessary that $f=g$ on $\Omega$, But is there a simple example that shows this?

Comment: Can you think of a non-zero function that still has $\int f d\mu = 0$ (over every measurable set)?

Comment: As the question is currently written, yes.  But It's possible that the question was referring to a stronger condition, that $\int_E f\, d\mu = \int_E g\, d\mu$ for all (measurable) sets $E$.  It is possible to find two non-identical functions which agree in this stronger sense... although they are almost identical.

Comment: It depends what you mean by $f = g$.  Do you mean "$f$ and $g$ agree almost everywhere", or do you mean that for *every* $x$, $f(x) = g(x)$?

Comment: Let $g$ be $f$ changed at a single point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $f$ is the indicator function of $[0,1]$ and $g$ is the indicator function of $[1,2]$ and $\mu$ is ordinary Lebesgue measure.  Then $\int f\,d\mu= \int g\,d\mu$ but $f\ne g$.

Comment: By $f$ and $g$ I mean that $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$ and $\mu$ is a measure on $x$.

Comment: @user3879021 : The function $f$ I defined above is given by $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } 0\le x\le 1, \\  0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$ That is a function of $x$.  And $g(x)$ is similarly a function of $x$.  And $\mu$ is a measure on the real line $\mathbb R$. $\qquad$